# Return caret postion or range of a div in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am wanting to return the start and end range or the caret postion inside a div. The div will have the attribute contentEditable.

typically I would use document.selection.createRange(); but the createRange function is broken in IE8 is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Broken how? the `createRange()` method of `document.selection` is no more broken than it was in IE 7 or 6, from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

`document.selection.createRange();` works the same in IE 8 as it did in versions 7, 6, 5 and 4. If you mean you want an object that works like a DOM `Range`, as all other mainstream browsers have, I'd suggest using [IERange](http://code.google.com/p/ierange/), which creates `Range`-like objects from IE's `TextRange`s.